# Countries banning electronic voting machines

Tags: electronic-voting

Germany has banned the use of voting machines which record the votes electronically only. Following is quoted from the [source](https://www.ndi.org/e-voting-guide/examples/constitutionality-of-electronic-voting-germany).

> The German Constitutional Court upheld the first argument, concurring that the use of the NEDAP voting machines was unconstitutional. The Court noted that, under the constitution, elections are required to be public in nature and
>
> *that all essential steps of an election are subject to the possibility of public scrutiny unless other constitutional interests justify an exception . . . The use of voting machines which electronically record the voters’ votes and electronically ascertain the election result only meets the constitutional requirements if the essential steps of the voting and of the ascertainment of the result can be examined reliably and without any specialist knowledge of the subject . . . The very wide-reaching effect of possible errors of the voting machines or of deliberate electoral fraud make special precautions necessary in order to safeguard the principle of the public nature of elections.*

So, is Germany now using paper votes only? Which other countries have banned electronic voting machines and on what grounds?

Comment: I don't think its saying paper votes only - I think its saying you can have an electronic voting machine if it also creates a paper record (ie you don't need to be a system technician to read the results). Honestly I think the logic there is a little weird, but I don't know German law well enough.

Comment: correct. so, of the few options available, what option are they using?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what your question is here.  Are you asking what Germans *currently* use to vote?  Or whether there are voting machines which *can* meet German criteria?  Or whether there are any other countries which have restricted the use of voting machines of this type (or all types)?

Comment: For those who are fluent in German, [here the complete decision by the BVerfG](https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Entscheidungen/DE/2009/03/cs20090303_2bvc000307.html).

Answer (score 2):

[The Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_voting_by_country#Netherlands) have also banned all electronic voting machines since the machines were famously hacked in 2006. On 2017-02-01 the Dutch government announced that all ballots in the 2017 general election would be counted by hand. There is a growing debate about the security of vote-counting software.

Comment: Could you please add details about the 2006 hacking?

Comment: @AmitMaurya: Did you click on the link and read the Wikipedia article?

Comment: Yes, I did. There are a few stories but without much details. I am not sure whether you are talking about the demonstration or other events in the same year. If you know more, adding  the same will help clarify and will be useful for other readers as well.